# bonded nics with netplan on Ubuntu 20.04 does not pass traffic

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, netplan, network-bonding

I've spent all afternoon trying to get some nics bonded on a Ubuntu 20.04 server. The bond seems to come up OK based on ip a and /proc/net/bonding but I can only ping the ip of the bond itself, everything else returns newtwork unreachable.

The netplan config is

```
    network:
      ethernets:
        enp1s0:
          dhcp4: false
          dhcp6: false
          optional: true
        enp2s0:
          dhcp4: false
          dhcp6: false
          optional: true
      bonds:
        bond0:
          interfaces: [enp1s0, enp2s0]
          addresses: [192.168.44.173/24]
          gateway4: 192.168.44.1
          nameservers:
                    addresses: [8.8.8.8]
          parameters:
                  mode: active-backup
                  #mode: balance-alb
                  mii-monitor-interval: 1    
                  primary: enp1s0
    version: 2
```

when I apply this config I get

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3a:16:23:70:af:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3a:16:23:70:af:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3a:16:23:70:af:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.44.173/24 brd 192.168.44.255 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3816:23ff:fe70:af55/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tailscale0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet6 fe80::20df:bfda:fa00:48e9/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

which looks to be OK, with routing as

```
default via 192.168.44.1 dev bond0 proto static 
192.168.44.0/24 dev bond0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.44.173
```

and /proc/net/bonding/bond0 as

```
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: enp1s0 (primary_reselect always)
Currently Active Slave: enp1s0
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 1
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
Peer Notification Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: enp2s0
MII Status: down
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:18:7d:d7:e9:aa
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: enp1s0
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:18:7d:d7:e9:a9
Slave queue ID: 0
```

I gave up on this and tried to revert back to a single interface with dhcp but now that nic comes up, but refuses to get any sort of address either (even when rebooted, which sits for over a minute waiting for an address now, before continuing without one).

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I've broken. Surely it can't be this hard.

Ta.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue must have been a corrupt arp table in one of the switches or something like that.

I came back to this after the machines were off for 24 hours and it just worked (both dynamic addresses and bonded nics).

Thanks to those that looked in.

For anyone looking, the configuration above does infact work.